# Grails GORM projection returning fewer column number than expected

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have this **projection** my criteria query:

```
projections{

                groupProperty('servey_id')

                sqlProjection 'sum(is_correct) as score, count(*) as total ', ['score', 'total'], [INTEGER, INTEGER]
            }
```

I have run the query on my mysql console and  am expecting a result like this:
**[[2,4]]**

but instead I get this:
**4**

**N.B** *The type of **is_correct** is boolean. It is okay to sum boolean in mysql but am not sure if it is possible in Hibernate*

any explanation?

Comment: Try adding `debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'` to your `log4j.main` block in `Config.groovy` to see what SQL is being generated.

Comment: Thanks, but the query seems right: select this_.servey_id as y0_, sum(is_correct) as score, count(*) as total  from response_log [inner joins] group by this_.servey_id limit ?

Comment: though I did not expect the additional column (this_.servey_id)

Comment: Well your code suggests you are trying to determine the number of total & correct votes per survey, thus `servey_id` is usually useful.

Comment: @GregorPetrin It is useful, I need it but I did not tell GORM to return that.

Comment: I'd say `groupProperty` implies it. Anyway, I ran a similar query and it ran as expected: how are you invoking that Criteria block? `withCriteria`, `createCriteria`..? Can you post that surrounding block of code, please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was this on my criteria query:

**resultTransformer org.hibernate.Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY**

Though I dont how this affects the projection.